# Sympy - computing 'implied' values from a function

Tags: sympy

I have the following function:

```
import sympy as sy
import sympy.stats as systats
def euro_vanilla_price(S, K, T, r, vol, call=True):

    N = systats.Normal("n",0.0, 1.0)

    d1 = (sy.ln(S / K) + (r + 0.5 * vol ** 2) * T) / (vol * sy.sqrt(T))
    d2 = (sy.ln(S / K) + (r - 0.5 * vol ** 2) * T) / (vol * sy.sqrt(T))
    norm_d1 = systats.cdf(N)(d1)
    norm_d2 = systats.cdf(N)(d2)

    if call:
        price = (S * norm_d1 - K * sy.exp(-r * T) * norm_d2)
    else: price = (K * sy.exp(-r * T) *( 1-norm_d2) - S * (1-norm_d1))

    return price
```

I So this particular function has 5 inputs (ignoring default call variable) and a single output. If i pass in some values as follows:

```
p,S,K,T,r, vol, call = symbols('p S K T r vol call')
exp = euro_vanilla_price(S, K, T, r, vol,call)

subs = {S:100, K:100, T:1, r:0.1, vol: 0.2}
price = exp.evalf(subs = subs)
print(price)
```

Then everything works great and I get a price of 13.27... which is correct. However what I actually want to be able to do is pass in a price and 4 of the other values and compute the missing value. So I would like to set price = 13.27... S=100, K=100, r=0.1 and then have sympy 'back out' the vol = 0.2. I would like this to be generic for any unknown value given the others. I have spent several hours experimenting with various options but to no avail. I used to do this by writing a seperate function for each unknown and starting with a 'guess' and then recomputing the price till it approaches a tolerance of the actual price (binary chop). This resulted in lots of repetitive code so would like to avoid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression and a desired value and all but one variables specified will result in an equation (perhaps complicated) in one variable. This is the sort of thing that `nsoslve` is good at. All you need is an estimate of what you think the answer will be (and there are lots of tricks to getting this value, but sometimes systems are well posed and forgiving in this regard and almost any initial guess will work):

```
>>> guess = 1; val = 13.27
>>> nsolve(exp.subs({S:100, K:100, T:1, r:0.1})-val, guess).round(2)
0.20
```